# Will non-Lego remote controls work with Lego IR receivers?

Tags: power-functions, clone-brands, remote-control

I bought a KAZI model of a Chinese bullet train CRH400F a month back and want to use a remote control. I bought an IR receiver and remote control, but the other IR receiver is lost in the post.

So I'm thinking of buying a Lego IR receiver instead. Does anyone know if the Lego IR receiver ([code 8884-1](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/lego-power-functions-ir-receiver-8884)) will work with a non-Lego remote control (photo below)? In theory, so long as they are both on the same channel number it should be fine, right?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how faithfully the remote was copied, specifically if the electronics was copied as well as the form factor. If KAZI just took a four channel IR module that uses another protocol and stuck two of them into the casing, the sent signals would most probably be incompatible with LEGO's PF system.

The channel number is only a manufacturer convention, without any inter-corporally agreed upon standards, so there is no universally accepted "channel" for IR remotes.

Comment: @Downvoters, how could this answer be more useful, short of buying the copycat controller from the exact same company and testing it?

Answer (score 1):

The channel number does not have much influence in the success or failure of the transmitter-receiver configuration. It will only work if both radio transmitters use the same frequency and encoding for signals.

Comment: This is correct, except PF uses infrared transmitters and receivers, not radios.

Answer (score -1):

If you compare the internal circuitry of the clone remote to this official Lego one, if they look similar then it’s highly likely that they use the same protocol.
[image: Inside Lego train controller]

[Image source](https://nishioka.com/train/)